# Spring Config map of String to object

Tags: java, spring, spring-config

I'm trying to get a Map with `{"host1": DatabaseConfigurationProperty("abcd", "mytable", "user")}`, however my below code only generates an empty Map.

application.yml:

```
database:
  host1:
    hostname: abcd
    name: mytable
    username: user
```

DatabaseConfigurationProperty.java:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("database")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Component
public class DatabaseConfigurationProperty {
    Map<String, DatabaseConfiguration> database = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, DatabaseConfiguration> getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }

    public void setDatabase(Map<String, DatabaseConfiguration> database) {
        this.database = database;
    }
}
```

DatabaseConfiguration.java:

```
public class DatabaseConfiguration {
    String host;
    String name;
    String username;

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

MainConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
public class MainConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseConfigurationProperty databaseConfigurationProperty;

}
```

databaseConfigurationProperty.getDatabase() is returning as an empty Map.

Answer (score 0):

With `@ConfigurationProperties("database")` you are telling spring to map values under property `database` in yaml to the fields in your class `DatabaseConfigurationProperty`.

Hence `DatabaseConfigurationProperty` is expecting a field named database under database in yaml like

`database:
  database:
    host1:
      hostname: abcd
      name: mytable
      username: user`

If you have your yaml in this format, your example will work fine.

One other option you have is to let the yaml remain same and change

```
@ConfigurationProperties("database") to `@ConfigurationProperties`
```

Then the class would expect field `database` at top level which is present in your yaml already.

You also have to correct the field name `host` to `hostname` in `DatabaseConfiguration` or change the yaml property to match the names.

Comment: Is there a way to only autowire the `DatabaseConfiguration` for `host1`? Like if I ran the code with `-Ddatabase=host1`.